# ¿ Como imprimir numero aleatorios sin que se repitan en Java?

Tags: java, poo, colecciones

Estoy intentando ordenar un array, al cual le paso número aleatorio con **mathRamdom** y los ordene con el método burbuja.
Hasta ahí todo bien, solo que al mandar a imprimir el ordenamiento, me repite mas de tres numeros seguidamente, y quisiera que no me repita los números si no que todos sean distintos unos de otros.

```
int[] numberRamdom = new int[10]; // Creo el array
                //Recorro el array y le asigno numero aleatorios hasta el 50
for (int i = 0; i < numberRamdom.length; i++) {
    numberRamdom[i] = (int) (Math.random() * (50));
} 
                //ordenamiento burbuja
for (int i = 0; i < numberRamdom.length - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < numberRamdom.length - 1; j++) {
        if (numberRamdom[j] > numberRamdom[j + 1]) {
            int temp = numberRamdom[j];
            numberRamdom[j + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
                // Imprimo el resultado ordenado
System.out.println("Numeros ordenados con la burbuja: " + Arrays.toString(numberRamdom));
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola James, aunque se corrija en ordenamiento para aplicar el algoritmo del ordenamiento burbuja, es importante que obtengas inicialmente valores únicos en el array inicial, esto debes corregirlo, agregué respuesta.

Comment: Para obtener valores únicos puedes hacer uso de la interfaz Set, que no permite elementos repetidos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas ordenar tu array mediante el algoritmo de ordenamiento burbuja, debes realizar algunos cambios a tu código.

> Ordenamiendo Burbuja: (Bubble Sort) es un algoritmo de ordenamiento
> que busca mediante repetidas comparaciones de los elementos próximos,
> ordenar un conjunto de elementos.

```
   int[] numberRamdom = new int[10]; // Creo el array
   //Recorro el array y le asigno numero aleatorios hasta el 50
   for (int i = 0; i < numberRamdom.length; i++) {
        numberRamdom[i] = (int) (Math.random() * (50));
   } 

   //ordenamiento burbuja
    for (int i = numberRamdom.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (numberRamdom[j] > numberRamdom[j + 1]) {
                    //intercambio(numberRamdom, j, j+1);
                    int tempValue = numberRamdom[j+1];
                    numberRamdom[j+1] = numberRamdom[j];
                    numberRamdom[j] = tempValue;
            }
        }
    }
   /*for (int i = 0; i < numberRamdom.length - 1; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < numberRamdom.length - 1; j++) {
           if (numberRamdom[j] > numberRamdom[j + 1]) {
               int temp = numberRamdom[j];    
               numberRamdom[j + 1] = temp;
           }
       }
   }*/
  // Imprimo el resultado ordenado
   System.out.println("Numeros ordenados con la burbuja: " + Arrays.toString(numberRamdom));
```

Ejemplo de array inicial:

```
[2, 10, 39, 11, 20, 14, 17, 4, 44, 12]
```

Salida:

```
Numeros ordenados con la burbuja: [2, 4, 10, 11, 12, 14, 17, 20, 39, 44]
```

---

Pero **el código que genera el array inicial tiene un problema ya que estas ordenando un array el cual puede generar inicialmente numeros repetidos**:

```
   int[] numberRamdom = new int[10]; // Creo el array
   //Recorro el array y le asigno numero aleatorios hasta el 50
   for (int i = 0; i < numberRamdom.length; i++) {
        numberRamdom[i] = (int) (Math.random() * (50));
   } 
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numberRamdom));
```

Ejemplo de salida incorrecto con valores repetidos:

```
[2, 10, 2, 11, 39, 14, 17, 4, 44, 12]
```

**Debes realizar esta corrección para obtener valores únicos para tu array para obtener valores únicos.**

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();   
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
while (numbers.size() < 10) {

    int random = randomGenerator.nextInt(50);
    if (!numbers.contains(random)) {
        numbers.add(random);
    }
}
        
int[] numberRamdom = numbers.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
System.out.println("array inicial: " + Arrays.toString(numberRamdom));
```

---

Este sería el código sugerido para el problema planteado:

```
     //Obtiene array inicial.
     ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();   
     Random randomGenerator = new Random();
     while (numbers.size() < 10) {
       int random = randomGenerator.nextInt(50);
        if (!numbers.contains(random)) {
            numbers.add(random);
        }
     }
     int[] numberRamdom = numbers.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
     System.out.println("array inicial: " + Arrays.toString(numberRamdom));  

    //ordenamiento burbuja
    for (int i = numberRamdom.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (numberRamdom[j] > numberRamdom[j + 1]) {
                    int tempValue = numberRamdom[j+1];
                    numberRamdom[j+1] = numberRamdom[j];
                    numberRamdom[j] = tempValue;
            }
        }
    }
   System.out.println("Numeros ordenados con la burbuja: " + Arrays.toString(numberRamdom));
```

Answer (score 6):

tal vez podrías usar un método como el siguiente:

```
int aleatorioSinRepetir( int[] array ) {
   int ale = (int) ( Math.random() * ( 50 ) );
   for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
      if( ale == array[ i ] ) {
         return aleatorioSinRepetir( array );
      }
   }
   return ale;
}
```

Es bastante simple, genera un aleatorio, recorre el array para verificar si está en el, en cuyo caso, vuelve a llamarse a si mismo (recursión), si no está, lo devuelve.
Me falto decirte que la implementación del algoritmo de la burbuja es errónea, debe ser así:

```
if ( numberRamdom[ j ] > numberRamdom[ j + 1 ]) {
    int temp = numberRamdom[ j ];
    umberRamdom[ j ] = numberRamdom[ j + 1 ];
    numberRamdom[ j + 1 ] = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Podrías crear un método que valide si existe el nuevo número dentro del arreglo:

```
public static boolean numberExist(int iteration, int[] array) {
    int actualNumber = array[iteration];
    for (int j = 0; j < iteration; j++) {
        if (array[j] == actualNumber) {
            return true; //Si lo encuentra repetido devuelve verdadero, ya existe en el arreglo
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

El cual, recorre lo que va lleno hasta el momento del arreglo, y va comparándolo con el número que se va a insertar, si ya existe, devuelve un verdadero.

La forma de implementarlo sería en tu primer for:

```
//Recorro el array y le asigno numero aleatorios hasta el 50
for (int i = 0; i < numberRamdom.length; i++) {
    numberRamdom[i] = (int) (Math.random() * (50));
    if (numberExist(i, numberRamdom)) {
        i--; //Si devuelve true, se resta la posición para volver a generar el número
    }
}
```

Lo que hace, es restar 1 a la posición recorrida en caso de que exista el número, para volver a sacar otro número aleatorio en la misma posición.

Comment: Hola Marce, es una buena observación, pero la iteración del for dentro de numberExist, valida hasta antes de la posición actual j < iteración, por lo que el número ingresado previamente no se valida.

Comment: Perdón maestro, horrible metida de pata!!!